# Django - Trouble validating ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
def io_simulation(request):
    form = SimForm(request.POST)
    print('FIRST' + str(request.POST))
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    return render(request, 'App/simulation.html', {'title': 'Simulation'})
```

This view function shows that my POST data is being sent correctly, but it's not reaching my database. This is the output of the print statement:

> FIRST<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['dzowQoB3lk2IOOc19QXQDPZ3soJaxglaP76cURfjB6GMU3VBkHDe7IDhIp2CPpyK'], 'sim_concentration_range': ['3'], 'sim_concentration_range_2': ['4'], 'sim_concentration_range_unit': ['ppm']}>

If I use io_simulation as the action for my form submission then I get a NoReverseMatch error, and I don't get my POST data printed out. If I use this other function as the action:

```
def save_sim_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.POST.get('sim_concentration_range')
        request.POST.get('sim_concentration_range_2')
        request.POST.get('sim_concentration_range_unit')
        data=Sim()
        data.sim_concentration_range = request.POST.get('sim_concentration_range')
        data.sim_concentration_range_2 = request.POST.get('sim_concentration_range_2')
        data.sim_concentration_range_unit = request.POST.get('sim_concentration_range_unit')
        data.save()

        return render(request, 'nowhere.html')  

else:
    return render(request,'no/errors.html')
```

Then I do see my POST data get printed (and it's correct (output in blockquote above)), but I still get nothing in my database.

I cannot make any sense of the views structure and debugging. What is going on?

**Edits:**

**Forms.py:**

```
class SimForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sim_concentration_range = forms.DecimalField()
    sim_concentration_range_2 = forms.DecimalField()
    sim_concentration_range_unit = forms.ChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = Sim
        fields = ('sim_concentration_range','sim_concentration_range_2','sim_concentration_range_unit')
```

**models.py**

```
class Sim(models.Model):
    sim_concentration_range = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 5, default=1)
    sim_concentration_range_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 5, default=1)
    sim_concentration_range_unit = models.TextChoices('sim_cc_unit', 'ppm ')
```

**STEPS TAKEN FOR SOLUTION**

**- Remove variable definitions within forms.py SimForm function but outside of Meta class**

```
class SimForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sim
        fields = ('sim_concentration_range','sim_concentration_range_2','sim_concentration_range_unit')
```

**- Change TextChoices field in models.py Sim class to CharField**

**- Removed save_sim_data function from views.py and removed action declarations for the form in its html**

**- Changed URL pattern to use io_simulation view**

Comment: Can you add `SimForm` to your question? It's most likely that the form is not valid, you are not re-rendering the template with the form errors so you cannot see them. `form.errors` will contain all validation errors for the form after `is_valid` has been called

Comment: Hello @angeroverflow, also please add models.py to make sure your implementation is correct, then we can see what we can do with it

Comment: `sim_concentration_range_unit` is a `ChoiceField` but you've not passed any choices to it, it's never going to validate. Have a look at `form.errors` that will give you an idea of what's going wrong

Comment: @angeroverflow `models.TextChoices` is not a model field, it's a convenience class for creating choices. You should use a `models.CharField` instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types

Comment: @IainShelvington I have changed TextChoices to a CharField with a default value of 'ppm', and added choices to SimForm (two tuples). I can't see if it's made any difference but I still am not getting anything through to my database.

Comment: @angeroverflow can you print `form.errors` to see what the form is complaining about?

Comment: Hello again, also you don't have to write 
    sim_concentration_range = forms.DecimalField()
    sim_concentration_range_2 = forms.DecimalField()
    sim_concentration_range_unit = forms.ChoiceField()
in your forms.py because you already using ModelForm. Try removing them

Comment: @B.Okba I am sure I'd already tried that but that is now working, thank you. Can you write that as an answer?

Comment: @angeroverflow, done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of you are using ModelForm, you don't have to override the fields. so you can just type it like this:

```
class SimForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Sim
        fields = ('sim_concentration_range','sim_concentration_range_2','sim_concentration_range_unit')
```